# How to pass route with {id} to Datatable blade. To view specific user details

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

This is my route

```
Route::get('/view/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ClientController@view',
    'as' => 'view'
]);
```

This is my Client controller

```
public function view($id){
     $client = Client::where('id',$id)->first();
     return view('view',compact('client'));
}
```

This is my datatable

```
@extends('layouts.datatables_master')

@section('content')
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="clients-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Last Updated</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
@stop


@push('scripts')
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#clients-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('business.list') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'companyname', name: 'companyname' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'surname', name: 'surname' },
            { data: 'idnumber', name: 'idnumber' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' },
            { data: "actions",
                      "render": function(data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="{{route('view',1)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-search" title="View"></i></a>                                               <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"></i></a>    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"></i></a>'

                               ;}
            }

        ]
    });
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Problem

My Main issue is passing an ID for all users. If you check my `render` function on my DataTable I said `return route(view,1)` where it's 1. I want to pass `$id` but it says undefined variable. Please help.

Comment: you can write like /view/1. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You could return the generated route link from your controller like:

```
return datatables(Client::query())
        ->addColumn('actions', function ($client) {
            return [
                'edit_link' => route('view', [$id => $client->id]),
            ];
        })->toJson();
```

and render in your view as

```
{
    data: "actions",
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        return 
        '<a href="' + data.edit_link + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">' + 
        '<i class="fa fa-search" title="View"></i></a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">' +
        '<i class="fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit"></i>' +
        '</a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">' +
        '<i class="fa fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"></i>' +
        '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I also found another easier way of doing it. I said:  return '<a href="view/'+row.id+'" >. So i extracted the ID from the row parameter. The main confusion here was mixing php with JS. coz the minute you say curly braces {{}} console expects PHP code. thats why route wasnt working so i then replaced {{route('view',1)}} with "view/'+row.id+'". And it worked like a charm. Thanks again everyone for you time.

Comment: *There's more than one way to do it!* Glad, you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

the value of data should be an 'id', and use url() instead of route() :

```
{ data: "id",
    "render": function(data, type, row) {
       return '<a href="{{ url("view") }}/"'+ data +'>View</a>';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 return   '<a href= "view/' + 1 +'" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa fa-search" title="View"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the client variable to blade

```
{{ route('view',$client->id); }}
```

Comment: Your method says undefined variable client